# Gradle: exclude and include multiple groups/modules in single line from compile closure

Tags: gradle

this syntax may be not yet provided but I am asking to avoid redundant code.
Right now I am excluding jars like this

```
 compile ('com.mygroup:myJar:0.1.1-M1-SNAPSHOT+') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics'
    exclude group:'org.apache.avalon.framework'
    exclude group:'net.engio'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

How can i exclude multiple groups/modules on a single line of code, for example, this syntax

```
compile ('com.mygroup:myJar:0.1.1-M1-SNAPSHOT+'){
    exclude group: ['org.apache.xmlgraphics', 'org.apache.avalon.framework', 'net.engio', 'com.google.guava']
}
```

Or is there any other short code which does the same thing.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
compile ('com.mygroup:myJar:0.1.1-M1-SNAPSHOT+'){
    ['org.apache.xmlgraphics', 'org.apache.avalon.framework', 'net.engio', 'com.google.guava'].each {
        exclude group: it
    }
}
```

Note that this is leveraging a Groovy feature, not a Gradle feature.

Note also that I don't believe that `include` is a thing in this context (see the method summary [here](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html)).

Comment: sorry, i got error > Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.mygroup:myJar:0.1.1-M1-SNAPSHOT+, build_8ldbv989
a6fpj8vmr3c3ut3um$_run_closure2_closure11@7d15f996] on root project 'myproject'.

Comment: include module: 'module_name' in the compile closure not supporting, but i want only one jar from a group that i am already excluding, please help if possible.

Comment: @shivakumark.r.: Actually, yes, I don't believe `include` is supported in this context (regardless of whether you're using my trick or not).

Answer (score 0):

```
compile ('com.mygroup:myJar:0.1.1-M1-SNAPSHOT+'){dep ->
    ['org.apache.xmlgraphics', 'org.apache.avalon.framework', 'net.engio', 'com.google.guava'].each {group -> dep.exclude group: group }
}
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351401/how-to-exclude-multiple-groups-when-using-dependencies-with-gradle/44360394#44360394#answer-44360394).