# How to exclude multiple groups when using dependencies with gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

Just like this code:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    }
}
```

In an android app `build.gradle` file, when I want to dependency a remote library, how to use exclude group syntax to exclude multiple groups?

Although the code above is a right way, but it`s a little bit complicated.Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well basically 'exclude' is just a method belongs to 'ModuleDependency' class which accepts a 'Map' of 'group' and 'module' and there's no way to pass more.

However you can use 'Groovy' power in this case and for each 'group' from list to call method 'exclude' on 'ModuleDependency' and to pass current 'group'. Take a look at approximate code below.

```
compile() { dep ->
    [group1, group2].each{ group -> dep.exclude group: group }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Nice way to do that

Answer (score 3):

Using this solution with [*Groovy combinations*](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#combinations-java.util.Collection-) (Cartesian product) to exclude some list from **all** configurations:

```
/**
 * These artifacts must be excluded from all configurations and dependencies.
 */
final excludedModules = [
    'module-to-exclude-1', 'module-to-exclude-2'
]


/**
 * Exclude dependencies from all configurations.
 * This configuration solves an issue 
 * when the same transitive dependency is included by different libraries.
 */
configurations {
    [all, excludedModules].combinations { config, moduleToExclude ->
        config.exclude module: moduleToExclude
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example is here:

```
compile group: 'org.jitsi', name: 'libjitsi', version: '1.0-9-g4b85531', {
    [new Tuple('org.opentelecoms.sdp', 'sdp-api'),
     new Tuple('junit', 'junit')].each {
        exclude group: "${it.get(0)}", module: "${it.get(1)}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.